# Data bind to Array Angular 6

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have list of Array in a table , I want to bind input value with list of array Id separately to the array here my html `<tr *ngFor="let entressEmployee of EntressForEmployee; let e = index ">
               <td style="text-align:left">{{entressEmployee.Description}}</td>
               <td> <input type="number"  class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> </td></tr>` and my **EntressForEmployee**  Array look like this
[image: Incomming Array] I want to bind ID with my input value.

Comment: You can use[ (ngModel)]="entressEmployee.id"

Comment: how to bind with input value together for one of another  array?

Comment: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="entressEmployee.ID" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your input of `type='text'` and then bind using `[(ngModel)]` like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let entressEmployee of EntressForEmployee; let e = index ">
           <td style="text-align:left">{{entressEmployee.Description}}</td>
           <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Value" [(ngModel)]='entressEmployee.ID'> 
</td>
```

Finally don't forget to import `FormsModule` in your `AppModule` - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

you can use property binding

```
<td> <input type="number" value={{entressEmployee.ID}} class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
```

Comment: no, i want to **entressEmployee.ID** with input value together

Answer (score 1):

simply use `ngModel`

```
<td> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="entressEmployee.ID" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
```

Comment: can i push to array both of ID and input value?